# Filter and replace results from Invoke-CIMMethod

Tags: powershell, sccm

Wondering if you could advise on how I filter these results and provide something more readable.

Input:

```
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK -ClassName CCM_Application -ComputerName $computer -MethodName Install -Arguments $ccmArgs | ft -AutoSize
```

Output

```
JobId                                  ReturnValue PSComputerName 
-----                                  ----------- -------------- 
{010101010101010101010101010101010101}           0 CLIENT_NAME
```

0 = success, and so I'd like it to just return the Computer Name and 'Success' or something similar.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: To limit the output to some desired properties you can use `Select-Object` and to *translate* a value into its *description* you could use a calculated property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Olaf already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67457890/filter-and-replace-results-from-invoke-cimmethod/67458910#comment119233830_67457890), you can limit/rename the properties you want returned with `Select-Object` like this:

```
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK -ClassName CCM_Application -ComputerName $computer -MethodName Install -Arguments $ccmArgs |
Select-Object @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$_.PSComputerName}},
              @{Name = 'Result'; Expression = { if($_.ReturnValue -eq 0) {'Success'} else {'Error'}}}
```

Output would be:

```
ComputerName Result
------------ ------
CLIENT_NAME  Success
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, appreciate your answer. Working perfectly. I couldn't get the syntax correct at all, was killing my output.

Comment: @ferosi44 Thanks for the nice feedback. Being new to the platform you may not know this, but it's customary to mark the question 'done' by accepting the answer that solved your problem. You can do this by clicking the large checkmark icon ✔️ on the left side of the answer. Doing that helps others with a similar question finding it more easily.

Comment: Thanks again Theo, marked as answered now.